# Isolating CLI program that uses HOME environment variable to save state to perform parallel execution

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, environment-variables

**Background:**
Using a CLI utility that saves certain state in the user's home directory - on Linux and Unix uses location in `"$HOME"` environment variable. This program is executed in shell script in Jenkins job. Whenever there are two jobs running that use different input for the program, there is a conflict, since the program's state is saved in `$HOME` directory.

Trying to isolate the utility to the job run, I have thought of changing the `$HOME` environment variable, which seems to work for a limited test:

```
if [ -d "newhome" ]; then
  echo "newhome dir already exists"
  rm -r newhome 
fi
mkdir newhome
old_home="$HOME"
HOME="./newhome"

# rest of shell script is here

HOME="$old_home"
```

There could be multiple jobs using same utility, and even multiple concurrent runs of the same job. Are there any consequences of such change for the rest of the environment, other jobs, etc? Should I use `chroot` or some other method instead?

Comment: Hang on, do you really want to be deleting the home directories of all users on the system? Where are you running this script from? Not from `/`, and not as root, I hope!

Comment: You can override $HOME; it’s not read-only. Doing so may not prevent a utility from determining the same value in other ways (reading the passwd database, etc).

Comment: @terdon the script is isolated to Jenkins workspace, so the actual location is /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myJob. I should probably rename new home directory for clarity.

Comment: Ah, phew. That makes a bit more sense :)

Comment: You forgot `export`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `HOME` is already exported. Changing the value of an exported variable will not make it "un-exported". There is no need to export it again.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that the script actually deletes `newhome` which is a static string in the script, I see no serious issue with this workaround.

Deleting the `newhome` directory will be an issue if there are concurrent processes running this same script, as the directory may be removed by a new process while an older process is still using it.